# Any reference implementation of PCC algorithm out there?

Tags: parsers, lr-k

Currently I'm exploring LALR(1) lookahead generation algorithms to implement. I've implemented Aho and Ullman one from their textbook, but recently stumbled upon "A new analysis of LALR formalisms" paper by Park, Choe, Chang.

There they propose an efficient algorithm (commonly referred to as PCC) and provide proofs, performance measurements and pseudocode.

The paper is well-written and understandable, but I wanted to take a glance at the code for this algorithm. I've searched on google and on github and nothing was found (the queries were `PCC implementation` or `Park Choe Chang algorithm implementation`).

Does someone have an implementation of this algorithm available?